# white screen while running sencha+blackberry webwork application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have created sample Blackberry WebWorks project using sencha. It's working fine.
The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html> 
     <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"> 
        <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
        <title>Hello World</title> 
        <script src="www/sencha.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="www/cordova2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link href="www/resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            new Ext.application({
                launch: function () {
                    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
                           fullscreen: true,
                           items: [
                             {
                                dock : 'top',
                                xtype: 'toolbar',
                                title: 'My First Test App',
                                height:40
                             },
                             {              
                                xtype : 'panel',
                                html:"test"
                             }
                           ]
                    });
                }
            });
        </script> 
      </head> 
      <body></body> 
   </html>
```

In this project I defined sencha code in this file. But now I want to create project such that sencha code should be in separate file. But i'm getting white screen.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
         <head> 
            <meta charset="utf-8"> 
            <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
            <title>Hello World</title> 
            <script src="www/sencha.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <script src="www/cordova2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <script src="www/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="www/resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
         </head> 
         <body></body> 
    </html>
```

The app.js code is:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'SenchaDemo',
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],
    views: ['SettingPanel'],
    launch: function() {
         // Initialize the setting view
         Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaDemo.view.SettingPanel'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?", 
            function(buttonId) {
                if(buttonId === 'yes') {
                     window.location.reload();
                 }
             }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please help me. I spend more than one week. but not getting why is this error.

Comment: when i defined sencha code in index.html then sencha code works. but if i defined sencha in other file and give reference of the sencha cod efile into index.html ten its not working.

Comment: loading sencha component explicitly its working. but if i defined in app.js its not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an issue with Sencha rather than the WebWorks SDK.  I am not sure whether it is possible break down like that.  Refer to following link for more info on setting up the project structure.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command

Thanks